# Why doesn't the show() function in matplotlib.pyplot work more than once for the same Axes object?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Out of pure curiosity, I would love to know why the final `plt.show()` does not display both plots on `ax`. Only the first `plt.show()` seems to do anything, because only the plot of `y = sin(x)` shows up. Here is the code sample:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(1, 100, 10)

ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

plt.show()

ax.plot(x, x)

plt.show()
```

Appreciate any help on this, because it bugs me to not understand why this is the case, even after a lot of searches. PS: I know that the code is useless and dumb, but I would still like to know for future use.

Comment: Taking your code, we can look at two things. The subplots and how show() works

Comment: You could use `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)`, then `ax1.plot(x, np.sin(x))` and `ax2.plot(x, x)` and only then `plt.show()`.  How exactly `plt.show()` works, strongly depends on your environment, and whether you are running matplotlib interactively.  `plt.show()` works differently in a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: `plt.show()` typically shows the current plot, waits, and when you close the plot everything gets erased (so `ax` gets destroyed), after which the code resumes and would show the second plot. You'd need to create `ax` a second time after the first `plt.show()` for `ax` to be part of the "current" plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```py
## load libraries 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(1, 100, 10)
## assign first plot
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
#plt.show()

## assign second plot
ax.plot(x, x)

## render the plots
plt.show()
```

One reason why `plt.show()` didn't 'show' more than once.

1. You are using subplots.
2. Your plots are on the same axes
3. `plt.show()` display all **open** figures. Your `ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))` will be shown and the figure closed. The second is on the same `ax` and will not be shown anymore.

Documentation: [matplotlib.pyplot.show()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html)

[Alternate]
If however you call `plt.plot()` separately, (without subplots axes), you would get two plots; each with its own dimensions.
PS: below works in Jupyter (mybinder)

```py
## load libraries 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt1
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 100, 10)
## first plot
plt1.plot(x, np.sin(x))
## render first plot
plt1.show()
```

Followed by

```py
## second plot
plt1.plot(x, x)
## render the plot
plt1.show()
```

Clarity from the documentation: [matplotlib.pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html#) is a state-based interface to matplotlib

[Updated]
@JohanC lumping up the explanatory code and the alternate code.
The explanation 1, 2, and 3 remains.
The alternate code remain. or
OP can put the two plots on their own `ax`, and have `plt.show` each.
I didn't intend including this before. However, for completeness:

```py
## load libraries 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

## tuple of desired two axes
## unpack AxesSubplot on two rows 
fig, (ax1, ax2),  = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

## assign variable 
x = np.linspace(1, 100, 10)
## assign first plot
ax1.plot(x, np.sin(x))
#plt.show()
## assign second plot
ax2.plot(x, x)
## render the plots 
## Rendering might not be 'smooth' in Jupyter 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Note that `plt.plot` here will create a new plot when the first plot has been closed by the first `plt.show()`. If you call `ax.plot` after `plt.show` closed the figure, you are plotting on an already closed plot, which can't be shown anymore.

Comment: @JohanC Isn't that what the OP wants explanation on? The OP started of with ... *Out of pure curiosity*, ...

Comment: @JohanC You comment mixed up the **two** different code. In one, the reason was shown. In the 2nd one, an approach was shown which doesn't 'rely' on axes `ax`. The other alternative, which I didn't show but which uses the same principle is to 'put' each plot on their own axes, say `ax1` and `ax2`. The OP **wants** to show each plots **separately**.  Calling `plt.plot` followed by `plt.show` for each achieve this. Likewise, 'instantiating' two axes, then  `ax1.plot` and `ax2.plot` followed by a single `plt.show' also achieve OP's outcome. Moreover, OP was duly referred OP to documentation

Comment: Your explanation *"1. You are using subplots."* is very besides the question.  If you just call `plt.plot(x, x)` you are still using subplots, as matplotlib will automatically create one if no open figure is available. Also, what ever happens on your machine and your environment, can be quite different from what happens on another machine or another environment.

Comment: @JohanC. My answer was explicit from the onset that it's reproducible in Jupyter (mybinder). Secondly, you mixed up `ax.plot` and `plt.plot` from the way your original comment sounds (or appears to be). I stand by my (original) answer, with the reproducible code and reference to documentation. This, nonetheless the amendment (editing) I made after your comment. NB: your comment is appreciated. The clarity wasn't just there.